# Doubly LinkedList

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault, computer-science, doubly-linked-list

I have encountered Segmentation fault in my `PopAtEnd` Can someone please help me out

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};

Node* head = NULL;
Node* last = NULL;


void InsertAtBeg(int ele){
    Node* ptr = new Node();
    ptr->data = ele;
    if(head == NULL && last == NULL){
        head = last = ptr;
        ptr->next = NULL;
        ptr->prev = NULL;
        return;
    }
    ptr->prev = NULL;
    ptr->next = head;
    head = ptr;
}

void InsertAtEnd(int ele){
    Node* ptr = new Node();
    ptr->data = ele;
    last->next = ptr;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    last = ptr;

}

void PopAtBeg(){
    Node* temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    head->prev = NULL;
    delete temp;
}

//**Segmentation Fault**//

void PopAtEnd(){
    Node* temp = last;
    last = last->prev;
    last->next = NULL;
    delete temp;
    
}

void display(){
    Node* temp = head;
    int i = 0;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            cout << temp->data <<" ";
            temp = temp->next;
            i++;
        }
    cout<<temp->data<<endl;
    cout<<"Size of the list is "<<i + 1<<endl;
}

void search(int key){
    Node* temp = head;
    int  i = 0;
    while(temp->next != NULL){
            if(temp->data == key)
                cout<<key<<" is found at index "<<i<<endl;
            temp = temp->next;
            i++;
        }

}

int main()
{
    InsertAtBeg(7);
    InsertAtBeg(2);
    InsertAtBeg(9);
    InsertAtEnd(1);
    InsertAtEnd(3);
    cout<<"The linked list is : ";
    display();
    search(9);
    search(1);
    PopAtBeg();
    PopAtEnd();
    cout<<"The linked list is : ";
    display();

}
```

Thanks In Advance for your help.

Comment: You're actually not implementing a doubly linked list, but instead a bunch of static functions in the global namespace, performing actions on two also static pointer variables. I really doubt this segmentation fault would be the only problem (you can read on static/global variable behaviour), but wrapping those functions inside a class would be a good beginning.

Comment: Your `main` program should be much smaller.  You should be inserting at most 2 nodes and see if you can delete the last one.  If it doesn't work with 2 nodes, it isn't going to work with 5 nodes.  Then you should be able to debug your code to see where it goes wrong with a minimal amount of data.

Comment: Help yourself visualize the problem by drawing pictures. Then go through your code (preferably with the help of a debugger because it'll show you if you've made any bad assumptions about what a line of code should do) and try to draw the same picture. If you can't you'll have a pretty good idea where the bug is because it's where the pictures deviated.

Comment: Take a look at all the places you set `prev`. You'll see you never set it to anything but `NULL`. Discuss why you do that with [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: Which line in `PopAtEnd()` triggers the segmentation fault? What are the values of your variables at that point?

Answer (score 0):

As *user4581301* said, you have to set prev everywhere not to stay null. For example, what causes segmentation fault in `PopAtEnd()`  is that you say `last = last->prev;` and `last->prev` is NULL. So, you have to add this line:   `ptr->prev = last;` in `InsertAtEnd()` before `last = ptr;`

Comment: And of course, never forget to discuss this with your rubber duck! ```very important```